# Multisite ad server solution

Tags: multisite

If I am setting up a multisite WordPress installation, is there a solution that would let me manage ad inventory (multi)site wide? Can I place ads in various zones at various weights or percentages? Is there a way to auto-fill unused inventory? What are the best solutions out there?

Answer (score 1):

I didn't got anything close to OpenX.
Install their plugin Advertising Manager. Activate it side wide.
Use OpenX Free Hosted edition to backfill it.